# sick drivers don't have diagnostics

Tags: ros, diagnostics, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am bit surprised to see that sicktoolbox_wrapper and sick_ldmrs do not provide diagnostics messages. Is it on purpose or is it just by lack of time?

Is there any already implemented diagnostic node for lasers or perhaps a generic diagnostic for sensors that could be added to any driver? For instance, I am planning to write a node that will listen to laser topics and report if the publishing rate is wrong and maybe if the data is all zeros, etc. Or does it exist already?

Or maybe I could modify the sicktoolbox_wrapper code to add these features, but again, was it left out for a reason?

There is no python API for diagnostics_updater, and sick_ldmrs is a python node... so I would have to either implement some manual diagnostic mechanism, or create an extra cpp node to monitor the published messages...

Btw, is the python API on the list of things to do for diagnostics_updater?

Advices would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30824/sick-drivers-don%27t-have-diagnostics/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2012-04-16**:
I wrote a Python API for diagnostic_updater and submitted to the package authors for their inspection. I also wrote a diagnostic for the LDMRS using my python API. I will submit it as well to the package authors, if the python API is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sicktoolbox_wrapper was written before the diagnostics system was developed.  And no one has put the time in to upgrade it.  A patch to add support would be appreciated, and would be cleaner than a node which listens to the topic and publishes diagnostics.  There's definitely no reason not to do it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2012-03-29**:
Hmm... just checked out the code from their SVN repo, and it turns out that chadrockey added a diagnostic publisher on March 11 (r38989). Haven't tested it yet...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-03-30**:
That version will probably be released in Fuerte.